# Is it possible to send an parameter in a django url and use it in the javascript on loaded page

Tags: javascript, django, url, parameters

Im trying to send a parameter from django url to javascript. I want to do this to make the page more dynamic and load graphs based on this parameter. the javascript in my graph page is calling on an api to populate arrays for the data. I want the parameter to modify my api calls

url below

```
path('graphv2/<Currency>', views.graphv2, name='webapp-graphv2'),
```

javascript below I want the parameter to replace currency in the api url

```
var prevHour_endpoint = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=<Currency>&tsym=EUR&limit=60'
    var prevHour_defaultData = []
    var prevHour_labels =[]
    var graphData

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: prevHour_endpoint,
        success: function(data){
            graphData = data
            populateDataHourly()
            setPrevHourChart()
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is missing too many details. Where is this JS - directly in the template, or in a separate .js file? And please show the `graphv2` view that renders the template.

Comment: Hi Daniel the javascript is inside the graph template

Comment: def graphv2(request):
    return render(request, 'webapp/graphv2.html', {'title': 'Graphv2'})

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the parameter in the template context and use it like any other variable.

```
def graphv2(request, currency):
    return render(request, 'webapp/graphv2.html', {'title': 'Graphv2', 'currency': currency})
```

...

```
var prevHour_endpoint = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym={{ currency }}&tsym=EUR&limit=60'
```